# Permission denied: FastCGI: can't create server

Tags: apache2, debian, fastcgi, phpfarm

Using [PHPFarm tuturial](http://thejibe.com/blog/14/02/phpfarm) I tried to setup PHP version 5.4.45 on a  Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.9 (squeeze). I follwed the steps and then at the end in the apache2 error log file, I got this error:

`[crit] (13)Permission denied: FastCGI: can't create server "/vagrant/httpdocs/cgi-bin/php-cgi-5.4.45": bind() failed [/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/b56ecb9c2318fb1c45e816f6df92a48a]`

I tried some suggestions already but nothing works. any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original tutorial describes what to do: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/Running%20Apache%20with%20a%20dozen%20PHP%20versions.htm#permission-denied

Comment: I tried that but I got :chmod: cannot access `/var/log/apache2/fastcgi': No such file or directory

Comment: The only I worked for me was to chmod 777 for "/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/"